# Is PhoneGap slow or it is a bug?

Tags: android, cordova

After I have compiled and deployed the demo application to my Samsung Galaxy S II I noticed that the Sample PhoneGap App which comes with PhoneGap was not very responsive when pressing buttons and scrolling.

I also made a little app using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile, with 4 buttons everything was ok, but when I added more than 7 and my viewport needed to be scrolled, scrolling become to be very slow, the more buttons/widgets I had the slower the srolling was.

**Is this a bug specific to my mobile device or it is just how PhoneGap works:
The fact that PhoneGap apps feel slow on my phone including the demo?**

EDIT:

The same PhoneGap app served by an HTTP server from my laptop and launched in the standard Android browser works very smoothly

Answer (score 6):

Try setting your `targetSdkVersion` higher. Changing mine from `"8"` (i.e. Android 2.2) to `"14"` (Android 4.0) dramatically improved PhoneGap performance on phones running newer versions of Android. Most likely this enables certain performance-enhancing features such as hardware graphics acceleration.

For more info see my other answer about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12397768/233370

Answer (score 4):

Since PhoneGap and the frameworks that is used with it (JQM,Sencha Touch etc) are just working in a WebKit browser they can be slow if there's too much to render.

There's actually no bug with your device or etc.It's just that PhoneGap and the frameworks are not so good if you want fast response and so on.You can try your app in other devices and can observe that they behave the same.

Comment: Native application will always beat intepreted crossplatform stuff  in terms of perfromance but (possibly) lose in speed of development

Comment: Yep, but hopefully one day, with the advancement of more 'web' enabled apps this will change.

Comment: I also hope so since development with frameworks like that is much more easier if you have a web background.

Comment: The authors concern is that the same web app performs poorly under PhoneGap compared to the native web browser. I'm seeing this as well. My app runs great under Chrome for Android but is nearly unusable when running inside PhoneGap.

Comment: @MattZukowski I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It really doesn't. The app works in a browser on the same device. That's hardly native.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same Problems, after Update to Android 4.0.4 my Phonegap (Cordova 2.0.0) & Sencha Touch 2 - APP was very very slow.

But after I insert

```
super.appView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

the APP works fine, as before the update.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: Alternatively you can disable hardware acceleration in the app manifest.

Comment: @JonathanRowny & Walter - I'm confused. Shouldn't hardware acceleration make things faster? Why it's required to disable it for Android 4+ ! Can you please explain? I'm having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For improved performance you may not need Phonegap.

If what you need is quick cross platform styling but fast native components try a tool like nativecss.com It keeps the styling in CSS, but uses native components for everything else - so no HTML rendering delays or clunky animations.