# Delay in Click Events in PhoneGap with JQuery Plugin

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova

I am using PhoneGap 3.4.0 with the JQuery plugin for my Android project. Touch events are not working properly, with click events facing 300ms click delay. What seems to be the issue? How is it fixed?

Code sample:

```
$(element).click(function(){
     //my function
});
```

Answer (score 2):

300ms delay is normal thing in mobile webview, it's because of waiting for possibility of performing double tap, there is a way to bypass this with [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) library.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166749/why-is-phonegap-slower-than-browser/12397768#12397768) question, have you tried changing your target SDK setting in your `AndroidManifext.xml` to a later, more up-to-date API level? There are claims that changing from `8` (i.e. Android 2.2) to `14` (Android 4.0) dramatically improved PhoneGap performance on phones running newer versions of Android, probably because of having some hardware acceleration features disabled in lower settings. Also set your `android:hardwareAccelerated` to `true` and see if that helps.